# WICD Network Manager: Takes over a minute to cancel a network connection attempt. Forced to wait for DHCP client to timeout

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dhcp, wicd

Debian Buster XFCE using WICD.  I do a lot networking work: setup and diagnosis of routing and switching. As such, it's not so rare that I ask WICD to connect to a network that has no functioning DHCP server. Before upgrading from Stretch to Buster, I could cancel a failing connection pretty quickly. Now, on Buster, I click Connect; WICD brings up the interface; issues a DHCP Request; displays 'Obtaining IP Address'.  Assuming DHCP is going to fail, if I now click Cancel, WICD sits for over a minute before I can do anything else. I tried shortening `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` timeout, but no difference. From Debian packages, it seems WICD only went from `1.7.4+tb2-5` to `1.7.4+tb2-6` (Stretch to Buster), so quite possible the change in behavior is due to multiple factors. Really just need a faster way to kill a failing network connection, but hoping I can make WICD function as it did on Stretch, where I could immediately cancel a network connection attempt and try another a couple of seconds later.

Comment: As an alternative to WICD, look into network-manager's `nm-applet` and `nmcli`. I recently made the switch and couldn't be happier!

Comment: perhaps will try again.  Last time I tried network manager, hated it.  Too much like microsoft, thinking it knows want I want, making it harder to do things deliberately, and failing if you want to do anything other than just be a user (vs network tech).